# How to change the value of a column after a specific time in Sql server Data Base

Tags: sql-server, database, linq

I have create a table using the following Query in the Sql server data base Named with (Appointment-20160925160528) for Doctor Appointment schedule

```
USE [aspnet-Appointment-20160925160528]
GO

/****** Object: Table [dbo].[doctorschedule1]   ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[doctorschedule1](

[id] [int] NULL,
[date] [nchar](10) NULL,
[8:00Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
[8:15Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
[8:30Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
[8:45Am] [nchar](10) NULL,
[9:00Am] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

There are Five Column named with | 8:00AM | 8:15AM | 8:30AM | 8:45AM | 9:00AM |
AND the value of the column are .............     Booked   Available  Available  Booked Available

After creating the table the table look like this:

<kbd>8:00 AM</kbd><kbd>8:15 AM</kbd><kbd>8:30 AM</kbd><kbd>8:45AM</kbd> <kbd>8:00.. AM</kbd>
<kbd>Booked</kbd><kbd>Available</kbd><kbd>Available</kbd><kbd>Booked</kbd> <kbd>Available</kbd>

Now i want to change the value of the column ***8:00AM*** from **Booked** to **Available** if the current time of the system  is 7 hours 44 minutes and 59 seconds 7:44:59 AM

How i can do this for each column in the database table .i am very new to sql server databases .any working example will be very helpful for me and bundle of thanks for your great time <3.

Comment: Depending on exactly , whether you want a physical change or just appearance change. For physical I would suggest setting up a JOB that runs every ~15 min which runs a SPROC that would o this. To do it for appearance just setup a view, that calculates each columns based on GETDATE()

Comment: Please Can you give me an example link?

Comment: Your table has some serious issues. First is you have what is known as repeating columns. You really should consider a table of schedule appointments. You would then use a left join to that table and any NULL indicates they are not booked. You should consider using the time datatype instead of nchar. And seriously, nchar for string representation of time is overkill. There are no values that don't fit in the ASCII set. Using the time datatype lets you do date math on the values. You also seem to be missing a DoctorID or something along those line to identify which doctor the rows belongs to.